# Obter o nome do wifi conectado em C#

Tags: c#

**`Obs: Não tem muita explicação, apenas obter o nome do wifi conectado.`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você tem  que criar um WlanClient object

```
wlan = new WlanClient();
```

Ai você pode pegar uma lista de SSIDS que o pc está conectado com esse codigo:

```
Collection<String> connectedSsids = new Collection<string>();

        foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanInterface in wlan.Interfaces)
        {
            Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid = wlanInterface.CurrentConnection.wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Ssid;
            connectedSsids.Add(new String(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(ssid.SSID,0, (int)ssid.SSIDLength)));
        }
```

Para verificar se há conexão você pode usar o codigo abaixo

[System.Net.WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

```
public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            using (client.OpenRead("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instale o pacote nuget ManegedWifi

Comment: Por nada, se funcionar da UpVote e Marca como respondido :)

Comment: adicionei uma função para veirficar que há conexão, se o return for treu, vc executa o codigo se for false vc não executa

Comment: observação pode usar qualquer url para veirifcar se há conexão

Comment: não seria o caso de utilizar um try/catch?

Comment: Se ele quizer tratar a exceção sim, mas  caso somente queira verificar se há conexão pode utilizar a função, Alguns erros são ignorados quando utilizando o try e mesmo assim para aplicação

Comment: Bom terá que pegar o macAdress do wifi, pois quando ele está desligado não retorna macAdress

Comment: mas se a maquina tiver outra rede Ethernet isso pode dar problema

Answer (score 1):

Não sei fazer isso em C# puro, mais tem uma biblioteca pronta para isso, veja [aqui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/managedwifi/).

Peguei através desta resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/431975/6647038 em inglês.

Pode instalar através: **`Console do gerenciador de pacotes`**

```
PM> Install-Package managedwifi -Version 1.1.0
```

Veja como obter o nome do wifi: **(Obs: isso apenas funciona com wifi ligado)**

```
private string GetWifiName()
{
    WlanClient wlanClient = new WlanClient();

    List<String> list = new List<String>();

    foreach (WlanInterface wlanInterface in wlanClient.Interfaces)
    {
        Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid = wlanInterface.CurrentConnection.wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Ssid;
        list.Add(new String(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(ssid.SSID, 0, (int)ssid.SSIDLength)));
    }

    return list.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

O código acima gera uma exceção `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception` quando o wifi não está conectado, para resolver isso basta verificar se o seu wifi está conectado ou não, usando a propriedade `InterfaceState`, segue exemplo final:

```
private string GetWifiName()
{
    WlanClient wlanClient = new WlanClient();

    List<String> list = new List<String>();

    foreach (WlanInterface wlanInterface in wlanClient.Interfaces)
    {
        if (wlanInterface.InterfaceState == Wlan.WlanInterfaceState.Connected)
        {
            Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid = wlanInterface.CurrentConnection.wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Ssid;
            list.Add(new String(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(ssid.SSID, 0, (int)ssid.SSIDLength)));
        }
    }

    return list.FirstOrDefault();
}
```